# Recent Application View Access

Tags: android, android-layout, android-windowmanager

Is it possible to access the view (or any other reference) of the **recent application** on Android? That is the window that appears on top when you long press the home button on some devices.

I have not found it in the view hierarchy of my Activity, nor in the Window. The only notification I get is a loss of focus.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sorry. This is not being displayed by your process, but rather by an OS process, so it is not in your foreground activity's view hierarchy. The same holds true for things like `Toast`s.